# Implementation of __builtin_va_start(v,l)

Tags: c, gcc, variadic-functions

Going down the rabbit hole of variadic macros in glibc, I’ve reached `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8.2/include/stdarg.h` where, for example, the `va_start` macro is defined as:

`#define va_start(v,l)  __builtin_va_start(v,l)`

But I’ve been trying to look for the actual implementation of `__builtin_va_start(v,l)` without success. I’ve googled and grepped for it, and the furthest I’ve gotten to is [Microsoft’s implementation](http://bioen.okstate.edu/Home/prashm%20-%20keep/prashant/VS.NET%20setup%20files/PROGRAM%20FILES/MICROSOFT%20VISUAL%20STUDIO%20.NET/VC7/CRT/SRC/STDARG.H) for Visual Studio, which I suppose isn’t radically different.

Does anybody know where glibc implementation is?

TIA.

Comment: You will have to examine the source code for the gcc compiler itself, since (unless I'm mistaken) it's at that level that the built-in pseudo-functions are implemented. That source code is freely available on the web.

Comment: If you want a quick way to see what it expands to, just compile with -E in gcc.

Comment: What information do you seek, that's not contained in the man pages for va_start?  From my experience `va_list` declares a pointer, and `va_start` sets that pointer to point to some random location on the stack.  If you need to know the exact implementation on your system, one way to do it is to step through the assembly code with the debugger.

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves `gcc -E` expands `va_start` to `__builtin_va_start`, so it’s back to the starting point. :)

Comment: @user3386109 I was interested in the actual implementation, not so much in the usage/functionality, which I understand. I had found helpful posts and articles (such as the one posted above) but, as I’ve found out thanks to the first comment, the implementation in glibc is a lower level one.

Comment: @user3386109 Checking the actually generated machine code gives the most accurate answer for any specific compilation context. So compiling with `gcc -g` and running `objdump -d -S` on the object file is sufficient to evaluate the actual translation of the variadic functions. A quick `gcc -S` also gives you a readable assembler listing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To look in the source code of gcc, download the matching version from http://www.netgull.com/gcc/releases/  For example, the 4.8.2 version is at http://www.netgull.com/gcc/releases/gcc-4.8.2/ (82 MB).

The builtin keyword is handled at line 4169 of `gcc/builtins.c`

Comment: I think it’s a better practice to point to the official sources such as http://gcc.gnu.org/svn.html. I used `apt-get source gcc-4.8` as I have a Debian distribution.

As far as I understand it `frv.c` is architecture-specific, as the many directories under `gcc/config`.

The file you mean is `gcc/builtins.c`, right?

Comment: Be aware that those builtin functions (just like the standard headers) are intended to hide away implementation specific magic, and may be wildly unportable. `va_start()` can allocate memory btw, which must be freed using `va_end()`. That is the reason you cannot simply copy a `va_list` but must use `va_copy()`.

Comment: @Alf:  I looked around there when I posted, but didn't see an easy way to download, so I followed the "mirrors" link.  Thanks for the better link.  Also, i don't know what happened to the path.  It is now fixed and the config stuff is removed.

Comment: After your corrections I marked it as correct. Thanks for the pointers, I was in the middle of figuring it out myself.

For the curious type, in version 2.95 of GCC there was a “non-builtin” implementation at `gcc/ginclude/varargs.h`, which was the sort of thing I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

In general, to find how gcc expands the built-in gcc function whose name is '__builtin_*foo*', look in the gcc source for the declaration of the function 'expand_builtin_*foo*'.

Answer (score -1):

have a look at stdarg.h in kernel 0.01 linux for an idea - va_start is a macro that initializes ap with as an increment starting at the first argument plus its size (rounded to machine word size); va_arg sets ap as the type given, and increments further the ap in the same way (rounding the type to machine words)

```
#define __va_rounded_size(TYPE)  \
  ( ( (sizeof (TYPE) + sizeof (int) - 1) / sizeof (int) ) * sizeof (int)  )

#define va_start(AP, LASTARG)                       \
 (AP = ((char *) &(LASTARG) + __va_rounded_size (LASTARG)))

#define va_arg(AP, TYPE)                        \
  (AP += __va_rounded_size (TYPE),                  \
  *((TYPE *) (AP - __va_rounded_size (TYPE)) ))
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19249031)

Comment: since i had the same question and seeing this code i tought was straightforward, i just came back here, where the comments didn't me help at all and replied the answer, thanks.

Comment: @user66296 This is a `va_start` and `va_arg` implementation for the early version of Linux kernel for i386. Those macros cannot be implemented like this for other architectures and this is not really what OP asked for.