# Does the ordering of multiple va_end calls matter?

Tags: c++, c, variadic-functions

I have the following code:

```
va_list va[2];
va_start(va[0], fmt);
va_start(va[1], fmt);
process(fmt, va);
va_end(va[0]);
va_end(va[1]);
```

I've looked at various sites for documentation on `va_start` and `va_end`, and all they say is that `va_end` should be invoked for each `va_start` before the calling function returns.

What I am unsure about is whether or not the order of the calls is significant. In particular, is

```
va_end(va[0]);
va_end(va[1]);
```

sementically identical to

```
va_end(va[1]);
va_end(va[0]);
```

in the above sample code?

Comment: You might also be interested in `va_copy`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On *some* [old] implementations, `va_start` expanded to a left brace `{` followed by some declaration, and `va_end` expanded to a right brace `}` possibly preceded by some "finalization". Morally they should match. In practice, often but not always, order does not matter much (but in principle it does matter).

On recent GCC, these `va_start` and `va_end` macros expand to invocations of `__builtin_va_start` & `__builtin_va_end` so the compiler may care (perhaps in some future version) that these are *correctly* nested. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22642222/841108). So the "good" order should be:

```
va_list va[2];
va_start(va[0], fmt);
  va_start(va[1], fmt);
     process(fmt, va);
  va_end(va[1]);
va_end(va[0]);
```

<sup>In practice the order of `va_end` might not matter that much.</sup>

The indentation is mine to emphasize that `va_start` & `va_end` are "nesting"

Of course, you need to call `va_arg` to really retrieve variadic arguments (I hope that your `process` is doing that). [stdarg(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/stdarg.3.html) explains that well (for C code):

> Each invocation of `va_start()` must be matched by a *corresponding*
>          invocation of `va_end()` in the same function.

Notice the *corresponding* word (emphasis is mine). I believe it means that `va_start` and `va_end` are really *nesting* (at least in principle).

Comment: IIRC, no implementation's `<stdarg.h>`'s `va_start` ever did that. Some (pre-standard) `<varargs.h>` implementations did, but standard C and standard C++ have never had a `<varargs.h>` header.

Comment: Agreed. But implementations could do strange things.

Comment: Unless either standard requires a specific order of `va_end` invocations, no, implementations cannot do strange things.

Comment: Well, the __builtin_va_end is a strange thing, as every GCC builtins. And plugins could even add more strange builtins... And future versions of GCC are allowed to do more weird things with such builtins.

Answer (score 5):

The only relevant requirement in the C99 standard is:

> **7.15.1 Variable argument list access macros**
>
> 1 [...] Each invocation of the `va_start` and `va_copy` macros shall be matched by a corresponding invocation of the `va_end` macro in the same function.

There is no requirement for the order of multiple `va_end` invocations to match that of `va_start`, or to match the reverse of that of `va_start`, so implementations are required to accept either order.

You could even use a horrible mess like

```
void f(int a, ...) {
  va_list ap;
  goto b;
a:
  va_end(ap);
  return;
b:
  va_start(ap, a);
  goto a;
}
```

This matches all requirements of the standard, so implementations must accept it. As a result, even tricks where `va_end` expands to something with unmatched braces are not allowed.

In practice, I am not even aware of any current implementation in which `va_end` has any necessary effect at all. All the implementations that I've been able to find, at most set the value (or the first sub-value, depending on the type) to zero, which would make further use of `va_arg` fail, but would not cause problems if you omit `va_end` from your code. Most don't even do that. Now, I wouldn't actually remove it from code, since there are legitimate reasons why an implementation (current or future) may actually do something in its `va_end`, but you can assume that current and future implementations will at least attempt to implement it in a way that matches the standard's requirements.

The historic implementations which use `#define va_end(ap) }` are just that: history. They did not provide that macro in `<stdarg.h>`, and they did not even have a `<stdarg.h>` header. You shouldn't worry about them.

Comment: Okay but this is really only half the answer. Plenty of implementations do things that they're not "allowed" to do. Are there any here?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I know some pre-C89 implementations with `<varargs.h>` required `va_start` and `va_end` to lexically match, but I am not aware of any problem on any implementation of `<stdarg.h>`. Also, generally, "the standard says it's fine", if backed up, suffices as an answer. Sure, there are implementations that have bugs, and if any mainstream compilers exhibit those bugs it's nice to mention them in an answer, but discounting what the standard says merely because of hypothetical buggy implementations is new to me.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit And actually, I recently searched for implementations where `va_end` did *anything at all* with its argument that would cause problems if `va_end` were omitted, but I have not been able to find any example. So in practice, I think the standard's requirements are stricter than what implementations actually need.

Comment: I didn't say your answer should be discounted. I said it's not complete. Implementation realities _do_ matter, especially for a practical question like the OP's. However if you've looked into it and the answer is "you're fine", then great! Might be worth adding that into the answer.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Sorry, that may have come across a bit aggressive, and that wasn't what I was going for. Appreciate the suggestion, will do so.

Answer (score 2):

Just call va_end once for each va_start, but you need to use va_arg to grab the individual arguments. Here's an example: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdarg/va_start/

Also, I don't think the ordering matters.